# How is Schlimmstes used?

Tags: article

When looking for [Schlimmstes in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=tsp&q=der%20%40Schlimmstes), one finds all varieties of associated articles:

> **die** Schlimmstes verhinderten und der Vernunft da und dort Vortritt verschafften.

> von **dem** Schlimmstes gefürchtet werden muss.

> **der** Schlimmstes verhindern soll:

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? What logic applies to result in the choice of articles for Schlimmstes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In none of the examples you quoted does "Schlimmstes" have an article ;) The words you marked are relative pronouns.

Let's look at simplified versions of the example sentences:

> Es waren die USA, die Schlimmstes verhinderten.
> It has been the US, who prevented the worst.

> Das ist das "Kreuz des Kindes", von dem Schlimmstes gefürchtet werden muss.
> This is the "cross of the child", from whom the worst is to be feared.

> Amtsleiter Pieper soll Schlimmstes verhindern.
> Head official Pieper is supposed to prevent the worst.

In all three examples it would probably be more natural to use "das Schlimmste" instead of "Schlimmstes" as a noun without an article. But the way it's phrased in the examples is completely correct.